# Material Design plugin in Sketch: How do you export the generated theme?

Tags: android, android-studio, themes, material-design, sketchapp

We are using the [Material Design Theme Editor](https://material.io/tools/theme-editor/) plugin in Sketch. It creates this amazing Style Guide and Material Design theme right in your Sketch file. Does anyone know to export then import the theme generated in Sketch to Android Studio?

Comment: you can find here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLrgDgd_1c0

Comment: I've watched this... It doesn't explain how to export that theme to give to a developer to add to Android Studio.

Comment: It's been a while, but did you learn how to export the generated theme for Android?

Comment: @GianMS -- nope. sorry

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Material Components for Android (MDC-Android) https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android.

The catalog module has demonstrations of all the components.
The material-theme-builder module lets you enter typography, shape, and color styling in Android Studio and then shows what the customized theme looks like. See the docs on the repo.

You can then design in sketch, manually add your chosen typography, shape, and color styling into material-theme-builder and check/fine tune how all the MD components look. Lastly copy the theme resources into your own project as per the repo docs.

It's not as simple as just exporting straight from sketch into your Android build.