# How will a developer using Android Studio benefit from the Material Theme Editor?

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, sketchapp

I apologize if the question title is confusing. I'm a bit confused myself.

I am an Android developer and have heard of the Material Theme Editor plugin for the Sketch app (https://material.io/tools/theme-editor/). I wished to use this plugin to design my next application.

As per a previously unanswered question here on Stack Overflow ([Material Design plugin in Sketch: How do you export the generated theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52444443/material-design-plugin-in-sketch-how-do-you-export-the-generated-theme)), I watched this YouTube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLrgDgd_1c0) on the basics of the Material Theme Editor.

However, the video only discusses how to work with the Material Theme Editor plugin, and not what to do when one is finished designing the theme.

I was wondering if Sketch or the plugin would generate a `styles.xml` file to copy/paste into Android Studio, or if I, a developer, would need to individually transcribe each design element into the `styles.xml` file.

Comment: i haven't used sketch myself so i could be doing it wrong, but where i work the designers mock up the app in sketch and i the developer add everything i need to styles.xml myself.

Comment: But is there a file that they share with you? Do you open the Sketch app/file yourself?

Comment: They don't share a file with me - they show me the mock ups - tell me the hex codes for the colours - and tell me to make an app that looks like what they made. That being said i would be happy to hear that I'm doing it wrong and there's an easier way

Comment: Wow... that sounds like a lot of extra work for you. Because now, with 
"personalized" material themes, some corners are rounded/not rounded, etc. There must be some other way.